# solution using only-32bit dll and only-64bit dll

Tags: c#, dll, process, 64-bit, wow64

1) i am wanting to use a 32-bit dll that is not available as 64-bit dll

2) another constraint: Im wanting to also use another dll the 32bit version of which does not work in WOW64 so the second dll has to be included as native 64bit dll...

what are my options for creating such a solution and make it work on a 64bit system?

as i understand it, it is not possible to reference a 32bit dll in a x64 project, so, unless there are better ways, should i build:

a) a mother x86 application (first 32bit-only dll reference problem solved)

b) and also build a separate sister x64 application that does the work with the second 64bit dll (second dll WOW64 incompatibility problem solved)?

if the above approach is feasible, i will need to execute the x64 sister process from the x86 mother process (which is in wow64), but i seem to remember that x86 apps are only able to spawn 32bit children (in wow64)? 
i.e. using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("64bitSisterApp"); from the 32bit mother app that is running in wow64 will fail?

any advice appreciated!

Comment: Why does this second dll not work in WOW64 exactly?  Do you have the ability to recompile the dll?  You need to post more information.

Comment: the second dll is difxapi.dll used for driver installation - i had many troubles with this on 64bit system and the only way to resolve those troubles was to compile in x64 using the native 64bit dll. the wow64 incompatibility is confirmed by microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548642%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: the first dll i cannot recompile unfortunately, the dll is provided by a third party (RIM/Blackberry) as 32bit only, to my knowledge (bbdevmgrps.dll)

Comment: I would suggest that you seperate the functions out. If your using difxapi.dll to install a driver it being its own process should resolve your problems.

Comment: 32 bit apps can spawn 64 bit apps, where ever you heard that it cannot is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you @Ramhound and @Joel ! I tried it and as long as project 1 was built as X86 and project 2 as X64 then starting app 2 from 1 did indeed spawn a 64bit process that could handle the second 64bit dll. Please would you copy your answer as a non-comment so i can accept it as Answer!